# Removing elements from an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, element, indices

#### Problem:

I have two arrays `A` and `B`:

```
A = [0, 1, 2, 3]; %A will always be from 0 to N where N in this case is 3.

B = [0, 1, 3,   1, 9, 4, 6,    2, 5, 9, 10, 11,   3, 8, 1, 5, 9, 10]; 

weights_B = [3, 4, 5, 6];
```

I want to compare the first element of `A` to the first `3` elements of `B` and the second element of `A` to the next `4` elements of `B`. If the elements of `A` are equal I remove it from `B`. So in example:

```
 if (A(1) == B(1:3))
 remove A(1) from B
```

Similarly,

I want to compare `A(2)` to the next `4` elements of `B` i.e. to `B(4:7)`:

```
if (A(2) == B(4:7))
remove A(2) from B
```

I want to compare `A(3)` to the next `5` elements of `B` i.e. to `B(8:12)`

```
if (A(3) == B(8:12))
remove A(3) from B
```

I want to compare `A(4)` to the next `6` elements of `B` i.e. to `B(13:18)`

```
if (A(4) == B(13:18))
remove A(4) from B
```

Note: The array `weights_B` determines the number of elements in `B` that should be respectively compared to `A(1), A(2), .. , A(4)`

So in the end `B` should have the following elements:

```
  B = [1, 3, 9, 4, 6, 5, 9, 10, 11, 8, 1, 5, 9, 10];
```

#### Needed Solution:

Is there any way I can do this without having to hard-code the indices?

Comment: I just read your comment on Siva's answer. Is there a rule, which element of A should be compared to which range in B? Why do you take 3 elements of B when comparing to A(1) and 4 elements for A(2) and A(3) respectively?

Comment: @Anton I am going to rephrase the question and make it more clear.

Comment: wait a bit, I have an idea

Comment: @Anton I changed the description with the required rules. Hope it is more clear for you. Thank you so much!

Comment: I posted a new version. try it please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way without hard-coding:

```
Bw = mat2cell(B, 1, weights_B); % split into chunks
result = cell(size(Bw)); % initiallize result
for k = 1: numel(A)
    result{k} = Bw{k}(Bw{k}~=A(k)); % fill each chunk of the result
end
result = [result{:}]; % concatenate into a row vector
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I choose your answer because it was the fastest to compute the problem I have when I use very large matrices.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of diversity, here's a way to do this using [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html):

```
function out = q50982235
A = 0:3;
B = [0, 1, 3,   1, 9, 4, 6,    2, 5, 9, 10, 11,   3, 8, 1, 5, 9, 10]; 
weights_B = [3, 4, 5, 6];

a_ind = 0; % acts as a "global" variable for the inner function

G = repelem( 1:numel(weights_B), weights_B ); % this creates a vector of groups
out = cell2mat( splitapply(@movdif, B, G) );

function out = movdif(B)
  a_ind = a_ind + 1;
  out = {B(B ~= A(a_ind))};
end

end
```

The above works because the order of processed groups is predictable.

This solution requires R2015b.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
A = [0, 1, 2, 3]; 
B = [0, 1, 3,   1, 9, 4, 6,    2, 5, 9, 10, 11,   3, 8, 1, 5, 9, 10]; 

weights_B = A + A(end);

border_0 = zeros(size(A));
border_1 = zeros(size(A));

border_0(1) = 1;
border_1(end) = length(B);

for i= 2:length(A)
    border_0(i) = border_0(i-1) + weights_B(i-1);
    border_1(i-1) = border_0(i)-1;
end

C = [];
for i= 1:length(border_0)
    shift = 0;
    if (i > 1)
        shift = border_1(i-1);
    end

    C = [C  B(    find(B(border_0(i):border_1(i))~=A(i)) + shift     )]
end
```

Comment: What if A = [0, 1, 2] and B = [0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 9, 11]; and now I also want to compare the 2 in A to 2, 3, 9, 11 of B. The answer should be B = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 9, 11]; Can you do this without having to enter the indices manually?

Comment: please read my comment to the question. We need a rule, which describes the mapping between elements in A and ranges in B.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The question specifically says _without having to hard-code the indices_

Answer (score -2):

```
   A = [0, 1]; 
   B = [0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6]; 
   % Split B into cells 
   C{1} = B(1:3) ;    % this can be coded if more splits are required 
   C{2} = B(4:end) ;
   % removing the lements 
   for i = 1:2
       C{i}(C{i}==A(i))=[] ;  % remove the elements in C{i} present in A(i)
   end
   cell2mat(C)
```

Comment: What if A = [0, 1, 2] and B = [0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 9, 11]; and now I also want to compare the 2 in A to 2, 3, 9, 11 of B. The answer should be   B = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 9, 11]; Can you do this without having to enter the indices manually?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The question specifically says _without having to hard-code the indices_

Answer (score -4):

Since you want to compare the elements of A with first 3 and then 4 elements of B respectively, you would need to involve indexes. 
You could simply use loop for it.

```
for(int i=0;i<B.length;i++){
 if((A[0]==B[i])&&i<3){
 B[i]=B[i+1];
 }
 else if((A[0]==B[i])&&i>3){}
  B[i]=B[i+1];
 }
```

Then adjust the updated size of array B.

Comment: Edit: in else statement, use A[1]

Comment: This isn't Matlab code. Also, the question specifically says _without having to hard-code the indices_

Comment: Please respect the language tags attached to the question.  The question is tagged MATLAB.